# ¿Como mostrar los ultimo registros por patente?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

#Estimados estoy con un problema en esta consulta dado que un estimado me ayudo un poco. Pero tengo un problema porque la clave foránea ya no me muestra el dato que necesito y estoy con ese problema. He estado leyendo pero no he logrado hacerlo que funcione bien.
#Estimado como puedo usar DATEDIFF en esa consulta. mi antigua consulta era

```
:SELECT id_seguro_obligatorio,DATEDIFF(vencimiento_seg_oblig,CURDATE()) AS contador,patente_tracto,n_poliza,date_format(fecha_seg_oblig,'%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_seg_oblig , date_format(vencimiento_seg_oblig,'%d-%m-%Y') as vencimiento_seg_oblig,valor_seg_obligatorio,archivo_seg_oblig FROM seguro_obligatorio INNER JOIN tracto ON tracto.id_tracto=seguro_obligatorio.tracto_id_tracto
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: yo no entiendo tu problema...

Comment: @gbianchi lo que quiero es hacer una consulta que solo me muestre los datos en azul cálido y no he logrado hacerlo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin ánimo de ser antipático, el funcionamiento de [DATEDIFF en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) es lo primero que encontrarías de haberlo googleado. Como sea, lo importante es que la función acepta campos de tipo DATE o DATETIME, indistintamente. La respuesta siempre viene en días.

Por lo anterior, lo que llamas `contador`:

```
 DATEDIFF(vencimiento_seg_oblig,CURDATE()) AS contador
```

Representa los días que han pasado desde que venció el seguro obligatorio hasta el presente. Cuando el seguro sigue vigente `contador` será negativo.

Obtener "las filas en azul claro" equivale a tenernos buscando las 7 diferencias. Sería menos críptico expresarlo como: "obtener los registros cuyo seguro obligatorio esté vencido". Esto lo pondrías en la cláusula WHERE, por ejemplo

```
SELECT <tus campos>
FROM <tus tablas y joins>
WHERE DATEDIFF(vencimiento_seg_oblig, CURDATE()) > 0
```

Comment: gracias por su respuesta esta consulta que he publicado es para ir mejorando. Tiene la razón con el datadiff algo que funciona igual he estado buscado otra forma.